# What do you do with all the leftover components from a server purchase?

Tags: hardware

So when I buy a server from HP, it typically pays to start with a pre-configured Smart-Buy and then add all the junk I want in it to the order.  So what should I do with all of the stuff that came pre-configured but has been replaced by upgraded components?  (for instance I'll have 460W power supply, a couple sticks of RDIMMs, a DVDRW, and maybe some other stuff)

Does this stuff go into your mountain of spare parts that'll never be used?  Do you bother trying to eBay it for the company?  Is there a top secret IT parts swap program? :)

Comment: Post-Modern Sculpture.

Comment: Rule #1 of the TopSecretITPartsSwapProgram is "You do NOT talk about the TopSecretITPartsSwapProgram." ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put them in a box in the back of some storage area. Only when the server is replaced should these bits and pieces be disposed of. Things change and you can never be totally certain of what you may or may not require in the future. Some of that stuff you describe can be used to maintain other machines, even if only temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy enough kit from HP they'll give you built-to-order kit at set-config prices so I tend not to be left with spares. What I do have ends up collecting dust in storerooms then being thrown out years later :)

Great question btw.

Comment: s/Dell/HP/ for me but same net result

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a box (pile) somewhere, and call a local recycle organization.  Often times they will take it away for free if the stuff is potentially able to be sold.

If you want to have a chance at money, sell it online.  Usually it's not worth the bother from what I've seen, and the recycle/let-someone-else-sell-it is cheaper overall.

Also, make certain to ask if you can order without these kits.